# I'm not getting an Error but the code is not working the way it should

Tags: c#

I have made a post form where "professors should enter their username and password to be able to post,and I don't get any error about it.
but when I run it, even if I enter the right username and password, it would always just do the "else" command.
Here's my code

```
 protected void Button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string postname = this.Postuser.Text;
        string postpass = this.Postpass.Text;
        string posttitle = this.TOP.Text;
        string postbody = this.BOP.Text;
        string sqlstr2 = "select * from professors WHERE pname='" + Postuser + "' AND ppass='" + Postpass + "'";
        DataTable dt1 = DBFunction.SelectFromTable(sqlstr2, "DBS.accdb");
        if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string sqlpost2 = "insert into post2(Professor,Title,Body)";
            sqlpost2 += "value('" + postname + "','" + posttitle + "','" + postbody + "')";
            DBFunction.ChangeTable(sqlpost2, "DBS.accdb");
        }
        else
            this.Label1.Text = "Posting on this wall is only allowed for profesors and it seems that you're not one";          
        DataList1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Learn to use SqlParameters and, if the problem continues, [edit] your post to include a [mcve]

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code and checking if your logic pertains to what is required in your case? From the looks of it, your SQL query is not returning anything.

Comment: When you debug, what is the runtime value of `sqlstr2`?  Not what do you assume it to be, but what do you *observe* it to be?  The described behavior is simply telling you that there are no rows matching your query.  So your first step should be to actually look at your query.

Comment: I'm using oledb connection , so i don't think that I can use sqlparameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following line of code, you are trying to concatenate PostUser and PostPass controls instead of their text properties

The following code should be changed:

```
string sqlstr2 = "select * from professors WHERE pname='" + Postuser + "' AND ppass='" + Postpass + "'";
```

Update your code like this to postname and postpass variables which are holding text values of user and password

```
string sqlstr2 = "select * from professors WHERE pname='" + postname + "' AND ppass='" + postpass + "'";
```

**Note:** Your code in vulnerable to sql injection attacks so you must use parameterized query

Comment: yes you are right, i've done it by mistake ...ithis solved the problem